# If the matrix of the quadratic form $Q$ in some basis is $A^\top A$ then $Q$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $A\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ and $Q:\ \mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is a quadratic form such that $\big[Q\big]_{\mathcal B}=A^\top A$ for some basis $\mathcal B$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Then $Q$ is positive definite.

My solution : for all $u\in\mathbb R^n$, we have
\begin{align}
Q(u)&=\big[u\big]_{\mathcal B}^\top\big[Q\big]_{\mathcal B}\big[u\big]_{\mathcal B}
\\ &=\big[u\big]_{\mathcal B}^\top A^\top A\big[u\big]_{\mathcal B}
\\ &=\big(A[u]_{\mathcal B}\big)^\top A\big[u\big]_{\mathcal B}
\\ &=\big|v\big|^2\,\geq\,0
\end{align}
where $[v]=A[u]_{\mathcal B}$.

Suppose $Q(u)=0$, then $|v|=0$, which implies $v=0$. Therefore $Q$ is positive definite.

Is my proof correct ? What do you think ?

Comment: You have to show that $Q(u)=0$ implies  $u=0\,.$

Comment: You need one other step $v=0\Rightarrow u=0$.